# CMake wrong path to *.so files

Tags: c, build, cmake

My project configuration is like:

```
proj/main.c
proj/myinc.h
```

My program uses external libs, added manually by me:

```
proj/include/inc1.in
proj/include/inc2.in
```

and

```
proj/lib/lib1.so
proj/lib/lib2.so.1
```

To my CMake file I add them like this:

```
add_library(lib1 SHARED IMPORTED)
add_library(lib2 SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET lib1 PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/lib1.so")
set_property(TARGET lib2 PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/lib2.so.1")
```

and link it:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} lib1 lib2)
```

Also, I must copy these two libraries to `/usr/bin` to run my executable later.

```
install(FILES ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/lib1.so DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib)
install(FILES ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/lib2.so.1 DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib)
```

Then I use: `cmake . && make && sudo make install` 
Then I remove proj/lib dir.

But when I run my built file, it asks for the library in `proj/lib/`, but not in `/usr/lib`:

```
$ /usr/bin/app
app: error while loading shared libraries: lib/lib1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Question: How to make my built app use shared libraries from **/usr/lib**?
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Perhaps, this is an RPATH issue? Consider reading [this](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling).

Comment: I don't know exactly. I added set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "/usr/lib") and 
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE). But still program search for *.so in proj/lib

Comment: How do you know it looks in `proj/lib`? The error message shows `lib/lib1.so`, which is a relative path, which could correspond to *either* path.

Comment: If i delete proj/lib folder the program throws that error. So how can i set my builded app to search libs in /usr/lib (not in proj/lib)

Comment: Also, what is the value of `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`? Did you change it? This defaults to `/usr/local`, which suggests your libraries will be installed to the `/usr/local/lib` directory...

Comment: It is set as: set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX /usr)

Comment: BTW, setting `CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH` to True is telling CMake to look in `proj/lib` for your libraries after installation. It sounds like you could start by removing that line.

Comment: I havent added that line to my CmakeLists.txt

Comment: Well, for resolve the *relative* path `lib/lib1.so` into `/usr/lib/lib1.so` you need to set `/usr` as RPATH. However I find quite strange that CMake tells the linker to embed `lib/lib1.so` into the executable instead of `lib1.so`. It would be interesting to look into output of `ldd /usr/bin/app`.

Comment: ermvad@huanan-intel-linux:~/$ ldd /usr/bin/app
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffdfa1bd000)
        libuv.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuv.so.1 (0x00007f04c3099000)
        lib/lib1.so (0x00007f04c2e3f000)
        lib2.so.1 => /lib/lib2.so.1 (0x00007f04c2e39000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f04c2c47000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f04c2c24000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f04c2c1e000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f04c30e2000)

Comment: Hm, into the executable it embeds library `lib2` with build location `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/lib2.so.1` as `lib2.so.1`, so the runtime loader is able find it under `/lib/lib2.so.1`. But it embeds `lib1` with very similar build location `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/lib1.so` as `lib/lib1.so`, so the runtime loader is not able to find it with default settings. I found this funny. Note, that `lib2` is found not under `/usr/lib/lib2.so.1` as your installation implies. Be careful when pollute system directories like `/lib` or `/usr/lib` with your toy libraries.

Comment: Thakns for your reply. So, how to make executable embeds libraries from /usr/bin instead of ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib

Comment: Noticed smth intresting. Lib2.so.1 always visible for linker, but lib1-no : lib/lib1.so => not found
lib1.so.1 => /usr/libi2.so.1
Very strange...

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding libs directly to `target_link_libraries`:

```
target_link_libraries(
        ${PROJECT_NAME}
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/lib1.so
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/lib2.so.1
)
```

Installation:

```
install(FILES ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/lib2.so.1 DESTINATION /usr/lib)
install(FILES ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/lib1.so DESTINATION /usr/lib)
```